# Angular Elements - External library's CSS

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I was hoping to use Angular Elements with an external library (Kendo UI). I managed to create a component and add it to my app. The problem is that Kendo's CSS messed up with all my app styling.

Any idea on how could I encapsulate the CSS to only apply to the component and not "leak" to the rest of the parent app?

Thanks

```
UPDATE
```

See the following stackblitz for the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpmnjg

If I build the code I get 4 .js files and styles.css file (containing Kendo UI's styles). Adding the files to a clean html page works fine. But as soon as I add them to my app, the styles.css bleed out to my app, messing with the styles (buttons/inputs/etc).

Comment: Where Are you adding the kendo,  if it is as I suspect globaly, try add it only in the components you use, in styleUrls

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in a stackblitz or post code?

Comment: @TemkitSidali how would I add it directly through styleUrls? I tried but I always get an error that it can't find the file.

Comment: @HobojoeBr , check the path, something like this worked fine, 
  styleUrls: ['./elements-test.component.css','./../../_kendo.scss'] , you can see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpmnjg

Answer (score 1):

Without having knowledge of Kendo UI and having only read about angular elements, in general how I'd encapsulate the CSS is use SASS and do

```
.angular-element-class {
  @import 'path/to/kendo.css';
}
```

or hopefully if Kendo UI has SASS api

```
@import 'path/to/kendo.scss';

.angular-element-class {
  @include kendo-mixin-needed-for-angular-element;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your approach but I get some errors like:
`".angular-element-class .k-button[disabled]" failed to @extend "%disabled".
The selector "%disabled" was not found.
Use "@extend %disabled !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.`

Comment: Since kendo is not really scoping their styles i am afraid that will result in the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

create a `_kendo.scss` and import all necessary stylesheets:

```
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/dropdownlist';
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/grid';
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/input';
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/popup';
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/tabstrip';
....
```

You need to have the kendo npm modules installed for this to work.

then in your styles.scss

```
@import './kendo';
```

**UPDATE:**

My guess is that they are bleeding through because they are globally imported. So lets say you have

```
<kendo-grid>
...
    <table>
      <th>
```

The styles from the grid will bleed through to your table because kendo does css as such:

`.kendo-grid th { ...`

So really there is not a way around it except for creating counter-rules which is more than terrible, we had to do it in our project too. 
We are getting rid of `kendo`, it is not well fit for angular.

*maybe* you can get around it by only importing

```
@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/grid';
```

in the component itself an not globally. Although I have not tested that. Also it will replicate the SCSS in every component that imports it and blow up bundle size.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried implementing your approach (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpmnjg) and after building, i get some js files and a styles.css. It works on a blank html. But if I add them to an app, the styles.css file bleed into my app styles as it has a lot of styles for html tags. I don't see how it would solve my problem. Have I done something wrong??

Comment: Can you name/show any example of the leaking styles? Per default the view encapsulation keeps them intact

Comment: There is no view encapsulation on `styles.scss`

Comment: No but in every other component. are you styling globally?

Comment: I think I know why @WilliamLohan. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me just to remove the .css file extension.

So instead of having your import statement as

```
@import 'path/to/file.css'
```

you could try to do something like

```
 @import 'path/to/file'
```